# Cross platform menu with Cordova

Tags: android, ios, cordova

Simple question:
I need a menu that works within iOS, Android and Windows Phone using apache cordova.

I found a few examples like this [here](http://www.raymondcamden.com/2012/5/30/Example-of-adding-menu-support-to-a-PhoneGap-Application)

But they are all not working fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The better option is to use html5 frameworks,my suggestion is to use ionicframework (http://ionicframework.com/) which will covers all of your needs.